# MvvmCross: Binding progress bar in iOS

Tags: ios, xamarin.ios, mvvmcross

I would like to know how to bind the **UIProgressView's Progress** property.

Having this in the design:

```
[Outlet]
MonoTouch.UIKit.UIProgressView ProgressIndicator { get; set; }
```

I've tried the following:

```
set.Bind(ProgressIndicator).For(p => p.Progress).To(vm => vm.IosProgress);
set.Bind(ProgressIndicator).For("Progress").To(vm => vm.IosProgress);
```

In the ViewModel I have:

```
private float _iosProgress;
public float IosProgress
{
    get { return _iosProgress; }
    set { _iosProgress = value; RaisePropertyChanged(()=>IosProgress); }
}
```

**UPDATE AS REQUESTED:** 
 - I have an iPhone 4 with iOS7.
 - I have tried to bind the IosProgress indicator to a Label, works perfectly, having tested with 3 values, 0.33333, 0,666667 and 1 showing in the label.

I created two screen captures for you.

1. This is showing the value of the IosProgress indicator during debug with initial value given in constructor as 0.1f, also the debug message.
   [image]
2. This is showing the 3 versions I've tried, having the same faulty results, debug message for the current one:
   [image]

Thank you!

Comment: Looking at the doc's and the intellisense, I think `Progress` should bind automatically on its own. What messages do you get in the trace when you try to use `set.Bind(ProgressIndicator).For(p => p.Progress).To(vm => vm.IosProgress);`. It may help if you can include what iOS device and version you are running on, and if you can also bind `IosProgress` to the Text of a `UILabel` in order to check that it is changing as you expect it to.

Answer (score 2):

I just tried the `SeekView` in https://github.com/MvvmCross/MvvmCross-Tutorials/tree/master/ApiExamples with a `UIProgressView` like:

```
    public override void ViewDidLoad()
    {
        base.ViewDidLoad();

        var label = new UILabel(new RectangleF(10, 100, 100, 30));
        label.Text = "Slide me:";
        Add(label);
        var seek = new UISlider(new RectangleF(110, 100, 200, 30));
        seek.MinValue = 0;
        seek.MaxValue = 100;
        Add(seek);
        var pro = new UIProgressView(new RectangleF(110, 130, 200, 30));
        Add(pro);

        var set = this.CreateBindingSet<SeekView, SeekViewModel>();
        set.Bind(seek).To(vm => vm.SeekProperty);
        set.Bind(pro).For(v => v.Progress).To("SeekProperty / 100");
        set.Apply();
    }
```

This worked exactly as expected on an iOS7 iPhone simulator.

The only problem I had was if the `ViewModel` property went outside the `0.0f` to `1.0f` range.

Comment: `SeekProperty / 100` => `Mind = Blown * 100`